# Ping via nmap all possible private IPv4 addresses

Tags: ping, nmap

Is there any way to ping via nmap (using one command) all the possible private IPv4 addresses from: 192.168.0.0 - 192.168.255.255. The number of all combinations is 65536.

Comment: RFC 1918 specifies more private IP addresses than 192.168.0.0/16. There are also 10.0.0.0/8 and 172.16.0.0/12.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do have (at least) two options.

Either you use the CIDR style notation, which would be

`nmap 192.168.0.0/16`

or you can use a range like

`192.168.0-255.0-255`

but I'd recommend

`192.168.0-255.1-254`

since addresses with .0 and .255 are network xor broadcast addresses.

So a complete request is for example

`nmap -sP 192.168.0-255.1-254`

From `man nmap`

> -sP: Ping Scan - go no further than determining if host is online

Comment: In versions of Nmap since 5.30 (March 2010), `-sP` has been spelled `-sn`. Also note that network/broadcast addresses depend on the size of the network.

Comment: It works! I guess this works with the other classes as well. (10.0.0.0 - 10.255.255.255, 172.16.0.0 - 172.31.255.255).